# Render a list in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, render

I am using this code inside a Sharepoint list to add a small icon behind the title. The code is showing the icon after the text but the list is not displayed like normally and not accessable anymore, like the code makes it into a screenshot.

```
<script>
(function () {
   var excludeRows = [0,2,3];

    function renderListItemTemplate(renderCtx) {
        if(excludeRows.indexOf(renderCtx.CurrentItemIdx) > -1)
        {
                return ''; //do not render row
        } else {
        var ret = renderCtx.CurrentItem.Title + "<img src='https://example.com/sites/ud07/HRM/Plaatjes/image.png'/>";
                return ret;
}
        return RenderItemTemplate(renderCtx);
    }

    function registerListRenderer()
    {
       var context = {};
       context.Templates = {};
       context.Templates.Item = renderListItemTemplate;
       SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);
    }

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerListRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
})();
</script>
```

What do I need to change to make it a normal render function that returns the list like normally?

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a reference of below demo:

```html
(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {
        var excludeRows = [0, 2];

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

            OnPostRender: function (ctx) {
                var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
                rows.forEach((item, index) => {                    
                    if (excludeRows.indexOf(index) == -1) {
                        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, item);
                        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);

                        let jqueryO = $(tr);
                        let tardiv = jqueryO.find("td>div[field='LinkTitle']");

                        tardiv.append("<img src='https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/sbdev/SiteAssets/MicrosoftTeams-image.png'/>");
                      
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Result:

[image]